# помогите сделать css градиент

Tags: html, css

[image: помогите сделать вот такой css градиент]
помогите сделать паттерн для этого градиента.
код он не совсем верный я думаю

```
body{
    background: 
    linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(229, 131, 82, 1)25%,rgba(248, 247, 187, 0)25%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,rgba(249, 252, 78, 1)25%,rgba(138, 138, 243, 0)25%),
    linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(138, 138, 243, 1)25%,rgba(249, 252, 78, 0)25%),
    linear-gradient(to top left,rgba(248, 247, 187, 1)25%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)25%);
    
    background-size: 8em 8em ;
    background-repeat: repeat; 
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Источник](http://css.yoksel.ru/css-patterns/)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #C0CCAB 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, #C0CCAB 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%) 3em -3em, linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFEFC3 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFEFC3 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%) 3em -3em, linear-gradient(135deg, #E57152 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%), linear-gradient(135deg, #E57152 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%) 3em -3em, linear-gradient(-135deg, #E8DE67 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #E8DE67 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%) 3em -3em;
  background-size: 6em 6em;
  background-color: #E8DE67;
  font: 10px/2 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```